# undefined reference to GLib

Tags: c++, c, linker, glib

I know, that there were many questions similar to mine, but their answers didn't solve my problem.

I am trying to build the CHamsa project:
https://github.com/maxsnew/CHamsa/

Got sary, patched it, built, installed. Built the TokenEXAPI. All was great.
When finally made the CHamsa with a makefile, it gave me errors:

**Makefile after typing 'make'**

```
g++ -o siggen tracesary.o utils.o tokenExtract.o conjpattern.o sig_gen.o siggen_main.o 
  -lm -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lsary -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0   -LTokenEXAPI -ltkex -lds_ssort -lbwtlcp
```

**errors**

```
/usr/local/lib/libsary.so: undefined reference to `g_free'
/usr/local/lib/libsary.so: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_destroy'
/usr/local/lib/libsary.so: undefined reference to `g_strdup'
/usr/local/lib/libsary.so: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_insert'
/usr/local/lib/libsary.so: undefined reference to `g_strconcat'
/usr/local/lib/libsary.so: undefined reference to `g_array_new'
/usr/local/lib/libsary.so: undefined reference to `g_array_free'
/usr/local/lib/libsary.so: undefined reference to `g_malloc'
/usr/local/lib/libsary.so: undefined reference to `g_assertion_message_expr'
/usr/local/lib/libsary.so: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_new'
/usr/local/lib/libsary.so: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_foreach'
/usr/local/lib/libsary.so: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_lookup'
/usr/local/lib/libsary.so: undefined reference to `g_strerror'
/usr/local/lib/libsary.so: undefined reference to `g_malloc_n'
/usr/local/lib/libsary.so: undefined reference to `g_array_append_vals'
/usr/local/lib/libsary.so: undefined reference to `g_log'
```

it looks like badly linked, because the file, which is using the **glib** has got:

```
 #include <glib.h>
```

any ideas how can I solve this one? I am sitting here whole day googling for answers...

this one was bad:

```
 g++ -o siggen tracesary.o utils.o tokenExtract.o conjpattern.o sig_gen.o siggen_main.o 
   -lm -pthread  -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0  -L/usr/local/lib -lsary -LTokenEXAPI -ltkex -lds_ssort -lbwtlcp
```

that one too:

```
g++ -o siggen tracesary.o utils.o tokenExtract.o conjpattern.o sig_gen.o siggen_main.o 
   -lm -pthread  -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0  -L/usr/local/lib -lsary -LTokenEXAPI -ltkex -lds_ssort -lbwtlcp
```

even that one:

```
g++ -o siggen tracesary.o utils.o tokenExtract.o conjpattern.o sig_gen.o siggen_main.o 
  -lm -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lsary -L/usr/lib  -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -LTokenEXAPI -ltkex -lds_ssort -lbwtlcp
```

### **EDIT**

Makefile looks like that:

```
    ###############################################################################
#
# File:         Makefile
# Description:  Guess
# Author:       Zhichun Li
#               Northwestern Systems Research Group
#               Department of Computer Science
#               Northwestern University
# Language:     Makefile
# Package:      N/A
# Status:       Experimental (Do Not Distribute)
#
# (C) Copyright 2006, Northwestern University, all rights reserved.
#
###############################################################################

CXX = g++
MV = mv
CP = cp
RM = rm
MKDIR = mkdir
TAR = tar cvf
COMPRESS = gzip

INC = $(shell pkg-config --cflags sary)
#CXXFLAGS = -Wall -ggdb -c ${INC}
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -O3 -c ${INC}
LIBS = -lm $(shell pkg-config --libs sary) -LTokenEXAPI -ltkex -lds_ssort -lbwtlcp


TARGET = test_tracesary 
TARGET = siggen
STATICLIBS = 
SOURCES = test_tracesary.cpp  tracesary.cpp  utils.cpp 
SOURCES = siggen_main.cpp  tracesary.cpp  utils.cpp tokenExtract.cpp conjpattern.cpp sig_gen.cpp
SOURCES = tracesary.cpp  utils.cpp tokenExtract.cpp conjpattern.cpp sig_gen.cpp
HEADER = utils.h tracesary.h bitvec.h globals.h

OBJS = ${SOURCES:.cpp=.o}

all: ${TARGET} siggen_nonoise

#utils.o: utils.cpp ${HEADER}
#   ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS}  $<

#tracesary.o: tracesary.cpp ${HEADER}
#   ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS}  $<

#test_tracesary.o: test_tracesary.cpp ${HEADER}
#   ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS}  $<

#siggen.o: sigen.cpp ${HEADER}
#   ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS}  $<

${TARGET}: siggen_main.o ${OBJS}
    ${CXX} -o $@ ${OBJS} siggen_main.o ${LIBS}

siggen_nonoise: siggen_nonoise.o ${OBJS}
    ${CXX} -o $@ ${OBJS} siggen_nonoise.o ${LIBS}

%.o: %.cpp *.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
clean:
    ${RM} -f *.o *~ ${TARGET} siggen_nonoise

cleanAll: clean
```

and I also tried it with

```
$(shell pkg-config --libs glib-2.0)
```

with no effect

Comment: You need to link libsary with glib. ALternatively you need to use `-rpath-link` when linking `siggen`. Will provide a more detailed later when I have time if you still have not worked it out.

Comment: Try to move the `-lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0` to the *very end* of the `g++` command.

Comment: by the **very end** you mean after the: `-lbwtlcp` ?

Comment: Yes. Does it work? (By the way you can inform commenters using "@username". For example, to inform me in your next comment, use @ace so that I can get a notification.)

Comment: @ace nope, it didn't. Thanks for info with that "@username" ;)

Maybe there is a problem with libs location? Orginally libsary.so was in '/usr/local/lib'  and the rest of libraries are in '/usr/lib/' 

I tried to add the path to a env variable, but I could do something wrong